# Excel Macro: I would like to add one column to a range and call a function to fill it

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a macro we use to build a worksheet with a subset of a larger worksheet.
When the loop finds a match in our array of server names, it copies it over to the new worksheet.
I would like to add a new column to the new worksheet during the copy process. And after getting that working, I would like to fill this field by calling a function. We are trying to have a column that shows whether a server is a "critical" server. Simple y/n returns from a function that would look in an array of critical servers. I don't need the function, just how to add a column and fill it during the loop.

I will paste the big loop farther down, but here is the individual line of code that would copy over a range if found to a new worksheet. It is here I would like to add or copy one more column filled by a function:

```
 Rcount = Rcount + 1
 Source.Range("A" & Rng.Row & ":R" & Rng.Row).Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount & ":R" & Rcount)
```

Here is the big loop for inquiring minds. It might be useful or at least prove this code is being used:

```
With Source.Range("A1:R9000")

    'Find where the actual data we need starts
    Set Rng = .Find(What:="Client", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

    intColorMatch = 0

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = Rng.Address
        Do
            Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            If (Rng.Interior.Color = 13421772) Then
                intColorMatch = intColorMatch + 1
            End If

            If (intColorMatch < 2) = False Then
                StartRow = Rng.Row
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If


    Source.Range("A" & StartRow & ":R" & StartRow + 1).Copy NewSh.Range("A1:R2")

    Rcount = 2
    FirstAddress = 0

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        'If you use LookIn:=xlValues it will also work with a
        'formula cell that evaluates to "@"
        'Note : I use xlPart in this example and not xlWhole
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                If Rng.Row >= StartRow Then
                    Rcount = Rcount + 1
                    Source.Range("A" & Rng.Row & ":R" & Rng.Row).Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount & ":R" & Rcount)

              ' Use this if you only want to copy the value
                    ' NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount).Value = Rng.Value
                End If

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "new" column that you are wanting to populate is after the end of your copied data, you aren't really adding a column - you are just populating an existing empty column.

If so, you can just say something like

```
NewSh.Cells(Rcount, "Q").Formula = "=whatever_formula_you_want"
```

(or use FormulaR1C1 if that is easier).

Or, if you only want to insert a value there (which you are calculating in your VBA code), it is just

```
NewSh.Cells(Rcount, "Q").Value = the_value_I_want
```